# Find if a time exists between two different times, type issue

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, posixct

I have a dataframe as so

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = c("11:15:00", NA, "15:15:00", "12:00:00", 
"18:40:00", "18:15:00", "7:10:00", "15:58:00", "10:00:00", "10:00:00"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I basically want to create a new variable which tells me if the time is in a certain group.

I wrote the following but it's not correct, tried changing to as.POSICxt but no dice.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(time_groups  = ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),00:00, 5:59), 1,
                        ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),06:00, 8:59), 2,
                        ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),09:00,11:59), 3,
                        ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),12:00,14:59), 4,
                        ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),15:00,17:59), 5,
                        ifelse(between(as.POSIXct(TIME),18:00,23:59), 6,
), NA)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `findInterval` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

a <- c("00:00","5:59", "8:59", "11:59", "14:59", "17:59", "23:59")
b <- ymd_hm(paste(Sys.Date(), a))

df %>% 
  mutate(Interval = findInterval(ymd_hms(paste(Sys.Date(), TIME)), b))

   TIME     Interval
  <chr>       <int>
 1 11:15:00        3
 2 NA             NA
 3 15:15:00        5
 4 12:00:00        4
 5 18:40:00        6
 6 18:15:00        6
 7 7:10:00         2
 8 15:58:00        5
 9 10:00:00        3
10 10:00:00        3
```